# Is a left outer join needed when I only need one column from the joined (right) table in the WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I have the following left outer join query:

```
SELECT table_left.pk_id, table_left.name
FROM table_left left outer join table_right on table_right.fk_id = table_left.pk_id
WHERE table_right.name like '%entered search value%'
```

The issue I have is that table_right has over 1,000,000 rows and over 60 columns.  The query takes around 1 minute and I think it's because it's doing a full outer join on ALL the columns.  I don't need all the columns.  I just need to use one column (table_right.fk_id) so I can join the two tables and another column (table_right.name) in the WHERE clause.

I use an outer join because I need to include results in table_left that don't have rows in table_right.

Any suggestion to help improve the speed of the above query would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an example of the two tables I have:

```
+-------------------+
| table_left        |
+-------------------+
| pk_id | name      |
+-------+-----------+
| 1     | IBM       |
+-------+-----------+
| 2     | Facebook  |
+-------+-----------+
| 3     | Google    |
+-------+-----------+
| 4     | Microsoft |
+-------+-----------+


+--------------------------------------------+
| table_right                                |
+--------------------------------------------+
| table_right_pk_id | fk_id | job_details    |
+-------------------+-------+----------------+
| 1                 | 1     | Tester         |
+-------------------+-------+----------------+
| 2                 | 2     | Toilet Cleaner |
+-------------------+-------+----------------+
| 3                 | 2     | Secretary      |
+-------------------+-------+----------------+
| 4                 | 3     | Developer      |
+-------------------+-------+----------------+
```

I'd like to be able to search on 'name' (in table_left) and also 'job_details' (in table_right) but use table_left columns.  This is the query I've come up with and under the query are some expected results:

```
SELECT table_left.pk_id, table_left.name
FROM table_left left outer join table_right on table_right.fk_id = table_left.pk_id
WHERE table_right.name LIKE '%searchTerm%' OR table_left.name LIKE '%searchTerm%'
```

**EXAMPLE 1**

searchTerm = 'IBM'

Result:

```
+-------------------+
| result            |
+-------------------+
| pk_id | name      |
+-------+-----------+
| 1     | IBM       |
+-------+-----------+
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

searchTerm = 'Tester'

Result:

```
+-------------------+
| result            |
+-------------------+
| pk_id | name      |
+-------+-----------+
| 1     | IBM       |
+-------+-----------+
```

**EXAMPLE 3**

searchTerm = 'Microsoft'

Result: (should still return Microsoft even if no record in table_right)

```
+-------------------+
| result            |
+-------------------+
| pk_id | name      |
+-------+-----------+
| 4     | Microsoft |
+-------+-----------+
```

**EXAMPLE 4**

searchTerm = 'Developer'

Result:

```
+-------------------+
| result            |
+-------------------+
| pk_id | name      |
+-------+-----------+
| 2     | Facebook  |
+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: try to use `explain` the sql to check how much rows scanned and which index used. and  a prepend `%` is not fast. anyway, mostly not because of too many columns.

Comment: Are you using an index when querying the right table?

Comment: I don't understand your statement about why you use a left join here.  Not saying it's wrong, I just don't understand *"I need to include results in table_left that don't have rows in table_right"* — A left join wouldn't exactly do this.  Left joins simply join rows from `table_left` but if none exist the results from `table_right` will still be included. Can you please include schema, sample data and expected output?  Make sure you have an index on `pk_id` on both tables — possibly a composite index on `name` and `pk_id`.  We really need to see more data to properly answer this question.

Comment: I've added 2 sample tables, my query and expected results.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return all of the results in the table_left (regardless of its a match), then a left join is correct, like you're doing, so don't worry about trying to switch that.

> The query takes around 1 minute and I think it's because it's doing a full outer join on ALL the columns. I don't need all the columns.

Let's be clear: The join is *only* operating on the columns that you've listed in the join conditions: In this case, table_right.fk_id and table_left.pk_id. 
However, you are correct that very large tables will take longer to process. If you don't need the rest of the columns, it is best to exclude them before you do any joins because the output table will be less wide (which means improved speed when returning that output table).

When trying to improve join performance, the rule of thumb in MySQL is to use indices. In layman's terms, an Index basically tells the database to use a specific column (or columns) as the lookup on the table. I've been blown away many times by the speed improvement after I added an index.

I strongly recommend using an index in this case. Here's a [great tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-create-index/) for setting those up. G'luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions S.S.  I'll look at the indices.  FYI, I've added 2 sample tables, my query and expected results in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Left join is fine:

```
SELECT table_left.pk_id, table_left.name
FROM table_left 
LEFT JOIN table_right on table_right.fk_id = table_left.pk_id
WHERE table_right.name LIKE '%searchTerm%' OR table_left.name LIKE '%searchTerm%'
```

> The query takes around 1 minute

That performance issue is not related to the join type.

It is most probably the "double ended" wildcards that are leading to long query times. These will NOT be improved by using indexes. Rules of thumb for you:

1. Use equal in preference to LIKE
2. Use LIKE 'something%' in preference to LIKE '%something'
3. Use LIKE '%something' in preference to LIKE '%something%
4. If you use LIKE '%something% don't expect lightning fast response times

Seriously, you need to re-consider that use of wildcards to improve performance. You can get index support to queries using a trailing wildcard, and if you build an index on the reverse of a column you can then get index support to a leading wildcard, but you would need full text indexing (and a different query) to get any index support for (the equivalent of) double ended wildcards.

---

Previously:

> I use an outer join because I need to include results in table_left
>   that don't have rows in table_right.

This simply makes no sense if you are filtering by just `WHERE table_right.name like '%entered search value%'`

ONLY rows where there is a match from table_right to table_left can be returned from that where clause.

Comment: If I use an INNER JOIN and I search on 'Microsoft' then won't it return an empty result?  I still want Microsoft to be returned (even though they have no records in table_right)

Comment: yes sorry you moved the goal posts  with an OR, but your performance isn't related to the join(s) or even then indexing **IF** you are using `LIKE '%...%'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overkilling your explanation and what appears you are trying to get.  If I am correct on interpreting your question, you want a LEFT JOIN.  You want from the LEFT table REGARDLESS of the right, but if the right happens to qualify your term, then get the entry as needed.

Your query was applying the criteria to the same left-table field instead of left and right.

To help optimize your query when joining to the RIGHT side table that has 60 (or more) columns, but you are only comparing on the FK_ID and its "Job_Details" (per your Tester and Developer query samples), I would build a composite index on just those two columns so it can be optimized for join and search … index on ( FK_ID, Job_Details ).  This way the engine can get the answer directly from the INDEX and not have to go back to the raw data pages where all 60 columns exist.  The Table_Left should ALSO have a composite index on ( PK_ID, Name ) for its optimization.

Now, your searching based on '%someValue%', you would need a full text search as the leading '%' is implying you don't know how many characters before the string, nor how many after, as long as the search string is SOMEWHERE within the query.  Unless you need that, I would suggest NOT using the leading '%', but that is your call.

```
select
      LT.PKID,
      LT.Name
   from
      Table_Left LT
         LEFT JOIN Table_Right RT
            on LT.PK_ID = RT.FK_ID
           AND RT.JOB_Details LIKE 'Tester%'
   where
         LT.Name Like 'Tester%'
      OR NOT RT.FK_ID IS NULL
```

So this would give you based on either the left-table having a name with 'Tester'
OR the corresponding right-table having a job details of 'Tester'.  But I don't think this is optimal.

However, I would actually suggest offering a different index on ( Job_Details, FK_ID), and then do a UNION query with DISTINCT.

```
select DISTINCT
      LT.PKID,
      LT.Name
   from
      Table_Left LT
   where
      LT.Name Like 'Tester%'
UNION
select 
      LT.PKID,
      LT.Name
   FROM
      Table_Right RT
         JOIN Table_Left LT
            on RT.FK_ID = LT.PK_ID
   where 
      RT.JOB_Details LIKE 'Tester%'
```

This way, the left-table is optimized for its distinct when finding by name and the right-table is optimized by searching for its JobDetails and getting corresponding left-table Name information.